# Should Google Analytics be considered in a site's privacy policy?

Tags: google-analytics, privacy-policy

Should one consider data being collected by Google Analytics when writing a privacy policy for a website using GA?

I lean towards no because that data is technically being collected and stored by Google, but I'm not sure.

Comment: While I do not believe there is a specific requirement (within the U.S. at least) it is recommended that any cookie including third-party cookies be accounted for. You do not have to echo how others use these cookies, but it does help to link to the privacy policies of the sites that implement the cookie. For example, example.com may not use cookies for itself. It would be best to mention that example.com uses GA and for performance analysis. It would also be best to link to Google's privacy policy for the benefit of the user. This can be a brief and simple paragraph with no complexities.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Google Analytics [terms of service](http://www.google.com/analytics/terms/us.html) actually require you to do that:

> You must post a Privacy Policy and that Privacy Policy must provide notice of Your use of cookies that are used to collect data. **You must disclose the use of Google Analytics, and how it collects and processes data.**

Comment: Seems like that requirement should be more prominent on GA.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with closetnoc, full disclosure is the best policy (but keep it brief).  The fact that you include GA on your site means that you are intending to use the data it collects, not to mention that Google gets to look at the data too.  The privacy policy has to do with the users of your website, not where their private data is stored.  Their data is being collected.